# OnKeyDown inside WebView fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I made a `Fragment`, containing a `WebView` and I wanted to define an `onKeyDown()` to get back from one web page to the previous one. I did it, but the weirdest part for me was to share a `WebView` variable from my `Fragment` class to my `Activity` class because I can't define `onKeyDown()` in the `Fragment`. So I just defined a get method and made it static. But I wonder if it was a real mistake and my app can seriously crash in some circumstances.

My `Fragment` code:

```
public class BrowserFragment extends Fragment {
    private static WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, parent, false);

        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_rus);

        webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new SwingBrowserClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Uri data = Uri.parse("http://www.swinginmoscow.ru/m/");
        webView.loadUrl(data.toString());

        return v;
    }

    public static WebView getWebView() {
        return webView;
    }
}
```

And my `Activity` code:

```
public class MainBrowserActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        return new BrowserFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && BrowserFragment.getWebView().canGoBack()) {
            BrowserFragment.getWebView().goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might work, but it is not a good idea. It could very well cause a crash if you don't handle the `Fragment` correctly or are somewhere in your code a little careless regarding its lifecycle. But there is an easy way around this. Instead of using a static method, save the instance and call methods on the instance itself. This way you can check if the instance is null and if not the `Fragment` can handle calls to `goBack()` or `canGoBack()` itself:

```
public class MainBrowserActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    BrowserFragment browserFragment = null;

    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        this.browserFragment = BrowserFragment.newInstance();
        return this.browserFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && this.browserFragment != null && this.browserFragment.canGoBack()) {
            this.browserFragment.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

As you can see the `BrowserFragment` instance is saved and then methods like `goBack()` or `canGoBack()` are called on the `BrowserFragment` itself. Of course you have to implement these methods in the `BrowserFragment` but that should not be a problem:

```
public class BrowserFragment extends Fragment {

    public static BrowserFragment newInstance() {
        BrowserFragment fragment = new BrowserFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    private WebView webView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, parent, false);

        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_rus);

        webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new SwingBrowserClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Uri data = Uri.parse("http://www.swinginmoscow.ru/m/");
        webView.loadUrl(data.toString());
        return v;
    }

    public boolean canGoBack() {
        return this.webView != null && this.webView.canGoBack();
    }

    public void goBack() {
        if(this.webView != null) {
            this.webView.goBack();  
        }  
    }
}
```

I made a few extra improvements to your code. First of all I added null checks to prevent any possible `NullPointerExceptions` and secondly it is recommend to always use a static factory method to create new instances of `Fragments`. That is what the static `newInstance()` method is  that I added to the `BrowserFragment`. The advantage of that is that you can implement a method which takes care of setting up the `BrowserFragment` for you regardless of where you use it. You can add parameters to `newInstance()` method to pass some value to the `BrowserFragment` or to add some required listener etc but since you don't pass any values to the `BrowserFragment` the `newInstance()` method remains pretty empty. Nevertheless it is best practice to always use such factory methods even if they only call `new BrowserFragment()`.

Generally this approach is much better. Especially from a architecture perspective because you don't directly interact with the `WebView` in the `Activity`. The `WebView` doesn't have anything to do with the `Activity`, it is part of the implementation of the `BrowserFragment` and as such the `Activity` should not know that there even is a `WebView`. How calls to `goBack()` or `canGoBack()` are implemented or what they exactly do is of no interest to the `Activity`. The  `Activity` just tells the `BrowserFragment` "I want to go back" and the `BrowserFragment` does the work. This separates the responsibilities better and makes the code more readable, more clear and more maintainable.

**EDIT:**

Also I don't know of a `SingleFragmentActivity` but generally any `Activity` implements `onBackPressed()` method. You don't have to override `onKeyDown()` to catch a back key event. You can just do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.browserFragment != null && this.browserFragment.canGoBack()) {
        this.browserFragment.goBack();
    } else {  
        // The back key event only counts if we execute super.onBackPressed();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

If you have any other questions please feel free to ask!

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much for you hard work and explanation! That is exactly what i wanted to implement, but had no idead how to(especially how to make the Fragment do the work an activity). My SIngleFragment Activity just contains the code of creating fragment, begining transaction and adding to container. Thank you! Now I'll go and meditate over your whole implementation =)

Comment: By the way, maybe you know, I added WebView to fragment so that activity lifecycle wouldn't affect page representation. For example I changed from portrait to landscape mode and i don't want my app to download starting page again. I should save something in saveInstanceState, but what should i save?

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the clear code and good explanation. It works perfectly for me! I just have one question, how can I handle when I have a menu in android that opens links inside of my webview? When I click in links inside of webview works nice but when I click in menu "Profile" and then I click in another menu and press back, it doesnt work... Any idea how can I fix it? :)